# Layout handle explanation about catalog/category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, update-handle

I would like to have a specific and precise explanation about the layout handle of **catalog/category** page.

From my knowledge i know that there are three different layout handles: `catalog_category_view`, `catalog_category_default`, `catalog_category_layered`

If we take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getLayoutUpdateHandle()` we will see:

```
public function getLayoutUpdateHandle()
{
    $layout = 'catalog_category_';
    if ($this->getIsAnchor()) {
        $layout .= 'layered';
    }
    else {
        $layout .= 'default';
    }
    return $layout;
}
```

So `catalog_category_layered` is loaded when **is_anchor** is set to **yes**, otherwise the `catalog_category_default` is the one who will be loaded.

And what about `catalog_category_view` ?

In my case, in my **catalog/product** page i have `catalog_category_view` as layout handle with a **layered navigation** and if I set some category to `is_anchor` to yes, Im still always have the same layout `catalog_category_view` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have multiple handles for the category page (certainly more than 5). If you want to know which handles is used for a specific page, you can for example add the following code in a template of the page :

```
<?php
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
?>
```

(for example in the `app/design/frontend/<your-package>/<your-theme>/template/catalog/category/view.phtml` template)

The `catalog_category_view` should be always present in a category page because, for each action of a controller, Magento will create an handle with the name `routerName_controllerName_actionName` ( the action called when you are on a category page is the `viewAction()` of the `categoryController.php` of the module `Mage_Catalog` that have for router name `catalog`).

If a category is set with `is_anchor` to yes, it should add another handle `catalog_category_layered` as you mentionned.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

- `catalog_category_view` is for all category pages
- `catalog_category_default` is only for pages that have anchor set to **no**
- `catalog_category_layered` is only for pages that have anchor set to **yes**